# Why ReferenceEquals() is faster than ==

Tags: c#, .net

I run the following code 10000 times(a and b are both instances of class C)

```
1.ReferenceEquals(a,b)  0.1 ms
2.a==b                  0.7 ms
3.a.Equals(b)           0.8 ms
```

Could you tell me why 1 is faster than 2 and 3...

Comment: What types are `a` and `b`? You could be calling an `==` with more meaning than the default one.

Comment: I can implement `Equals` so that it takes hours to execute. `Object.ReferenceEquals` does only have to compare two references.

Comment: `.Equals` is a virtual method, so I'd expect it to be slower than the others.

Comment: Why do you expect it not to be? Two references (internally) are just two integers. Subtract one from the other and compare the result to 0 (which can be, I believe, a single machine instruction).

Comment: @TimS.: Well .Equals(object) is - but this might not be that method. We really can't tell without knowing more about the class in question.

Comment: @TimS.: Unless `==` is overloaded, I'd expect 1 and 2 to be the same. A call to `Equals` being slower is easy to understand, but `==` less so. We really need to see the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing any code, but:

This is probably because the class in question has implemented the `==` operator, so that it doesn't compare references. Instead it likely is comparing the contents of the object in some way, which will of course be substantially slower.

(The `string` class does this, for example.)

Comment: Perfect. Just to be explicit: For a non primitive type, the `ReferenceEquals(a,b)` and `a==b` should have the exact same performance, since the comparison would be a "reference type" and not a "value type" on both.